# Свойства свойств и действий на форме

Tags: lsfusion

Пытаюсь попробовать разные свойства свойств на форме в рамках изучения платформы. Из документации не совсем понял как это делается, да и в открытых решениях использования свойств **regexp** и **regexpMessage** не нашёл.
В документации приведён пример по использованию, я применил:

```
MOVE PROPERTY(mobilePhone(m)) {
    regexp = '^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$'
}
```

Просто копирую и вставляю его в IDEA и естественно получаю ошибки ***Wrong escape sequence +*** и по остальным с обратным слешем. В связи с тем, что код не JAVA, предполагаю, что данный шаблон является вполне корректным, но неправильно обрабатывается IntelliJ IDEA, но решений в интернете мне найти не удалось.

Как результат - закономерный вопрос: как правильно использовать данные свойства?

Comment: Если код не Java, а IDEA рассчитана на анализ Java кода, то что вы хотите не совсем ясно.

Comment: В теге вопроса числится **lsFusion**, для которого IntelliJ IDEA используется как платформа для работы плагина. Сам lsFusion использует свой синтаксис для написания кода, отличный от Java.

Comment: @Александр, на самом деле IDEA поддерживает не только Java, еще, например, Kotlin, Groovy и т. д. (даже JavaScript в Ultimate Edition). А с помощью плагинной системы поддерживается на том или ином уровне еще множество языков. В данном случае речь идет о разработке с помощью lsfusion-плагина для IDEA.

Comment: Ну простите тогда)

Comment: Ну простите тогда)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша строка в языке LsFusion является строковым литералом.

"Для указания символов одинарной кавычки и обратного слэша необходимо использовать специальные последовательности '\'' и '\\'. Строковый литерал также может представлять собой локализуемую строку. В этом случае классом литерала будет TEXT, а вместо символов '{' и '}' необходимо использовать специальные последовательности '\{' и '\}' соответственно." -
https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Literals/#strliteral

Comment: } - тоже экранировали?

Comment: Удивительно, но заработало. Хотя в тексте чёрным по-русски написано, что данные последовательности используются только для локализованных строк, коими **regexp** не являются. Ну либо я просто читать не умею =)

Comment: В документации была ошибка. К сожалению для регулярных выражений в lsfusion пока что нет своего литерала, это строковый литерал, поэтому приходится добавлять еще экранирование. По поводу того, что это оказался еще и локализуемый строковый литерал.. Дело в том, что сейчас все строковые литералы, которые используются как значения свойств в инструкции `DESIGN` являются локализуемыми. В то же время в опции свойства `REGEXP` литерал является простым. Это, конечно, не слишком ожидаемое поведение. Надо будет подумать, как именно эту ситуацию улучшить.